# Trying to Automate a task with Gmail API

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am trying to create the proper credentials for the automation that I am creating with Gmail API. From what I see on the Google developer con nsole dashboard for OAuth2 credential creation, it requires me to add a domain.

The thing is, my automation does not lie inside a website, the code lies on a server in the cloud that runs my code infinitely that checks from certain emails solely in `"MY"` email. I never need to access anyone else's email but my own for this. I am confused about exactly what type of credentials I need if I am just sifting through my own email.

[image: Confused of what to add here]

If I don't have a domain that I am using for this.

Answer (score 1):

In order for Oauth2 to work the user (you) must consent for the application (client id, client secret combo) to access their data.

Once the user has consented the authorization code is then returned to the hosting aplication (redirecturi)

The screen you are looking at now is used to set up the consent for that is displayed to the user so that they have a way to contact you the developer.   I dont think those fields are required so technically you dont need to fill them out unless you are applying for verification of your project.  You probably wont need to apply for verification as you are using this only for your self.

What you will need to do is authorize your application once locally on your development machine save the refresh token and ensure that your code is able to access this refresh token and use it to request a new access token to request data from your account.

Without this your code is going to try and open up the consent form on the server which you wont be able to see and consent to.